# Whats the metal plate on some transitors with the big hole meant for?

Tags: transistors

[image: I mean the hole on top]

A lot of transitors have this metal plate on the back with a hole in the middle. Whats the purpose of that?

Comment: Heatsink connection.

Comment: Do transistors get that hot? Also are they internally connected to anything?

Comment: Yes, they can get that hot. The tab may or may not be internally connected; check the datasheet for the specific device in question.

Comment: @user2741831 Depending on what you use them for, they can get *very* hot. I was working with a device not too long ago that, at max load conditions, operated at nearly 120° celsius in a 20° room. (and that's *with* extraordinary measures to cool it!)

Comment: @hearth how many volts did that take?

Comment: @user2741831 It's not volts that matters in this case as much as amps; it was a DC-DC converter capable of outputting 100 amps DC. The majority of the power was *still* in switching losses. (100kHz is a lot to ask at this sort of power level, even with fancy silicon carbide switches)

Comment: I'd say it's *volts × amps* is what matters (where the volts is the voltage drop across the transistor, rather than the load). The internal temperature of the transistor will rise until the heat taken away through the tab = the power being dissipated, calculated by *P = V × I*.

Comment: @Transistor Sure, but it's not *operating* voltage that matters. There was no tab, either (it was a power module and was outputting a total of 550 watts of heat, no heatsink could make a TO-220 survive that), but that's beside the point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For attaching a heatsink.

That big metal part is bonded directly to the semiconductor die inside the device, allowing it to efficiently conduct heat away from the die and to the outside of the package. The hole in it is for a screw, to mount it firmly to a heatsink. Since it's bonded to the die, the tab (as it's called) is also electrically connected to the device, usually but not always mirroring one of the functions of the pins (frequently ground). This can be important when several devices share the same heatsink.

Incidentally, this type is called a TO-220 package. There are other packages designed for heatsinks, as well; TO-247, for instance, is another particularly common one with a similar shape; it looks like this:

[image: Front and back views of a TO-247 package.]

The TO-247 package is generally more effective at transferring heat (we engineers say it has a "lower thermal resistance") than the TO-220, but it's also slightly (as in fractions of a cent, but it still matters when you're buying millions!) more expensive to produce.

Some devices are also available in TO-220F packages, which are identical to TO-220 but with the tab insulated in plastic to avoid electrical contact to the heatsink; these look like this:

[image: Two TO-220 packages with insulated tabs.]

They are have much higher thermal resistance than the non-insulated kind, so you don't see them used very often.

There are other packages designed to screw onto heatsinks like this, and there are surface-mount packages with similar designs, but I think this answer is getting long enough already! Hope that helped.